# Cancelling one EF Core query and continue with another throws an Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Before executing a query with pagination and a lot of filters, I call `.CountAsync()` on it. It turned out that, for some filter conditions, `.CountAsync()` takes a very long time to finish (because of necessary joins) and the advantage of having the number available is not that important that it is worth the long waiting time.

Thus I decided to cancel the counting in those scenarios where it takes longer than one second and proceed with the actual query.

```cs
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ct = tokenSource.Token;
var totalCountTask = query.CountAsync(ct);
var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(totalCountTask, Task.Delay(1000));
var totalCount = 0;

if (finishedTask == totalCountTask)
{
    totalCount = await totalCountTask;
}
else
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}

items = await query
                .Skip((filter.Page - 1) * filter.PageSize)
                .Take(filter.PageSize)
                .ToListAsync();
```

But in cases where the count operation is cancelled, the next query executions throws an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. ...

But even though the task is cancelled successfully (I checked this in debug mode), it seems the previous query is still running in the background, preventing `DbContext` to do other work.

Is there any possibility to "free" the `DbContext` after cancelling a query to be able to use it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the query is aborted, it need to wait that abort is completed. Else, it's possible the second query start before the abort complete.

```cs
if (finishedTask == totalCountTask)
{
    totalCount = await totalCountTask;
}
else
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    try
    {
        await totalCountTask;
    }
    catch // swallow the exception from the abort
    { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves my problem and prevents from having to wait 6-8 seconds in some scenarios. Obvious, once I saw it :)

Comment: I don't see how swallowing an exception fixes the problem. It means that `await totalCountTask` didn't even run. But it's strange anyway that if `finishedTask == totalCountTask` you run `totalCountTask` *again*. Probably it's an artifact of slimming down code for the sake of the question but it may also explain why you consider this a fix: in reality it doesn't matter if `totalCountTask` runs again, or not.

Comment: @GertArnold It's waiting the task to finish that solve the problem. Because the task is aborted, it finish with a (expected) exception, that is swallowed.

Comment: Which exception?

Comment: @GertArnold, It's depend when the abort interfere. It's can be TaskCanceledException. If the query is running, it's the provider that throw. With Sql Server it's [SqlException](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/26).

Comment: @GertArnold If you want more lecture : [efcore - Issues - Distinguish cancellation from failure to allow different logging strategies](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19526)

Comment: We can keep discussing this, the main point is that this doesn't address the underlying flaw in the code, it's just covering it up, adding needless ceremonial orchestrating code.

Comment: @GertArnold, Do you mean to do the two queries in parallel? I agree, it's better. Why don't you post that as a answer?

Comment: I see, this is stuff for a discussion :) Usually, there are no parallel queries and I still do not see a flaw in the code. For pagination I need to aquire the total number of entities and therafter need to retrieve the current page's entities. Both SQL queries are awaited. But as written, for certain complex filter conditions the counting takes very long and I don't want the users to wait 10 seconds just to have the pagination controls, thus I opted to cancel the counting task after 1s. Awaiting it after canelling ensures it completes and DbContext can be used again. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is that a cancelled task isn't in a [`Cancelled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-taskstatus-canceled) state immediately after cancelling the cancellation token.

A cancellation token modestly signals that cancellation is requested, it's in no way capable of *effecting* cancellation instantly. It's an application programmer's task to make a process listen to the cancelation request. They will always try to stop a process "gracefully". What that means differs per task, but think of disposing `IDisposable`s, closing connections, etc., all aimed at preventing side effects. That will always take some time.

This simplified version of your code is (nearly always) guaranteed to throw the `InvalidOperationException`. When the commented line is commented out, it won't ever throw, because the task gets the (short) time it needs to abort.

```cs
var query = dbContext.Set<SomeTable>();

var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ct = tokenSource.Token;
var totalCountTask = query.CountAsync(ct);
await Task.WhenAny(totalCountTask, Task.CompletedTask);
tokenSource.Cancel();

//while (!totalCountTask.IsCompleted); // This "fixes" the exception
query.Load();
```

Needless to say, *this is bad code*. Normally, it shouldn't be necessary to orchestrate parallel tasks. The fundamental flaw in your case is that a `DbContext` instance is accessed by multiple threads. That should never ever happen. `DbContext` is not thread-safe. Each task should have its own context instance.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. Should have been abvious to me directly, but sometimes... However, vernou was a little faster and the try/catch seems totally OK to me. I don't understand why you conclude the DbContext is accessed by multiple threads. The problem was of course, that the first parallel Task had not been completed before using the DbContext again, but I do not see where there is another thread.

Comment: Well, frankly, I don't think that's a good fix, it just wipes the problem under the carpet. You do access the context from two threads, the one running `totalCountTask` and the one running `items = await query ...`. That's the problem and *that* must be fixed.

Comment: `Each task should have its own context instance.`, not true. DbContext isn't thread safe, but it can be used in asynchronous way.

Comment: From the documentation [EF Core - Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async) : `EF Core doesn't support multiple parallel operations being run on the same context instance. You should always wait for an operation to complete before beginning the next operation. This is typically done by using the await keyword on each async operation.`

Comment: @vernou Here for some reason a *deliberate* decision is made to not await all code. Such code should never share context instances.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: The  "not await all code" was the initial situation that caused me to post this question in the first place, because I misunterstood the concept of cancelluing. But with waiting until the cancelled Task is completed, everything is syncronized and thread safe again.